# CSS - Unable to change background colour of DIV - WooCommerce product description

Tags: css, wordpress, colors

This is probably a really simple fix but I've looked all over and I cannot get this to work. The issue is with WooCommerce in wordpress, I believe my overall CSS is overiding that of WC and causing me some colour issues.

Here is the page - http://www.chaotopia.com/product/connect-your-breath-bklt-cd/

I am trying to change the background of the product description from white to #272727 and the text to #ffffff. Also as you can also see the selected tab is white as is the text which is not ideal.

I'm assuming this is a CSS issue I've tried various things but cannot get it to work.

Can someone please guide me as to where and what I need to edit to fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I agree with Paulie_D. Also this seems more related to pure CSS than WooCommerce. Keep in mind that your theme's stylesheet probably loads before the WooCommerce stylesheet, which can cause your styles to be overridden by WooCommerce's styles without more specificity, `!important`, or loading a special stylesheet after WooCommerce loads its css.

Comment: Hi I also agree with you however I am a little stuck as to where my code even needs to be inserted at the moment with all the different style sheets hence I have not yet provided example code. I don't even know where the code is which is causing the colours in their present state. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following css in your active theme's stylesheet

```
.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs .panel{
background-color: #272727;
}
.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li{
background-color: #d3ced2;
}
.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li.active a{
color:#272727;
}
```

This should fix the problem. You can change the color values to what ever desired.

EDIT:

```css
.single-product.woocommerce #primary div.product .woocommerce-tabs .panel{
background-color: #272727;
}
.single-product.woocommerce #primary div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li{
background-color: #d3ced2;
}
.single-product.woocommerce #primary div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li.active a{
color:#272727;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the reply I just tried this but it doesn't seem to have worked. I literally placed it into the style sheet within my themes folder. I just placed it at the bottom of the sheet which may be were I am going wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try the new css. And let me know if it works.

Comment: Still not working unfortunately, to confirm I am placing it in the following: Home
 
chaotopia.com/wp-content/themes/zerif-pro/style.css and I am just placing it at the bottom, is that the right place? Thanks again for helping.

Comment: I can see the changes on the page of your website (except the tab text color). Try and refresh the page. May the updated css is not fetched in your browser. Try Control+F5.

Comment: Hi Just tried on two different browsers and mobile definitely hasn't taken effect, unless we have our wires crossed? Just to confirm I would like the background of the product description changed from white to match the background of the site so there should be no white sections here. Also I did not leave the code in there after I tried it so it shouldn't be showing if it is.

Comment: Well, I really wonder why its not reflecting. Its a pretty straightforward thing. I tried the css rules in browser style editor (which worked) and only then posted that. 
Can you add that css in your live file and let me check why is not getting applied? Will it be possible to retain the addition till I check?

Comment: Sure I've added it to the live file and saved it now. I'm sorry there's not more I can provide in terms of code etc bit of a difficult one!

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhh... buddy you have added those styles in the media query specifically for "print", that's why it is not getting applied. Here is what you need to do. In your theme's file (the file that you are editing is correct), you have to find this css rule `.woocommerce-page .woocommerce-tabs .entry-content`. This is should be approximately at line number 3674 in you file and replace that css rule entire with what is been suggested.

Comment: If you are editing the css file with-in wordpress editor, then I would NOT recommend that. Edit the css file on your local PC and upload it to the relevant location on server.

Comment: Epic that has worked zipkuden thank you so much! Final question is how do I change the colour of he text from black to white. Then this is sorted :D thanks again!

Comment: The product description text has inline css. That means from the wordpress/woocommerce admin area you have assigned color styles to it. (text editor UI). Remove the style form there and add corresponding css class in your stylesheet or within the text editor change the text color to white. And can you please mark the answer as appropriate?

Comment: Legend all sorted, it's because I had copied and pasted it from a word doc so dumped it into notepad and back out and then resolved. Thanks for your help!